# Deleting file from unknown directory with a dot in it in batch

Tags: batch-file, firefox, vbscript, wildcard

I'm writing a program that copies all files from the Firefox profiles folder

```
("system drive":\Users\"username"\AppData\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\)
```

in batch and VBScript, but when I copy the entire folder using a VBScript I made, it won't copy it all because of the **parent.lock** file.

I wanted a script to delete the parent.lock file from every sub-directory of the profiles folder, and all Firefox profile folders have a dot in them, so I tried using

```
(del "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.*\parent.lock")
```

but it won't work. I've also tried the command without Firefox open, and it still doesn't work. My current profile is

```
("my system drive":\Users\"my username"\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\a0kdlt22.default-1421383893044)
```

I also tried the same command, but with my full profile name, and it worked, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work": is there an error message, or does it just not delete anything? note that almost every file has got a `.` in it, separating file name from extension, e. g., `filename.txt`; Windows Explorer **does not display known extensions by default**, like `txt`; `lock` might be an unknown extension and is therefore shown; so open command prompt (*Start >> Run...*, type `cmd`, press _Enter_), type `dir /S /B "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.*"` to see all files within the target directory tree, including their extensions...

Comment: It doesn't delete it, and it's not the file I'm having trouble with, it's the folder that contains the file.The folder has a dot as well as the file, but I know the file name. I have my computer set to show all file extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in path to a directory or file. Windows command processor does not support that.

You can use for your task

```
del /F /Q /S "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\parent.lock"
```

which deletes the file `parent.lock` from all directories starting in profiles directory of Mozilla Firefox in application data directory.

Open a command prompt window, execute there `del /?`, and read entirely the help displayed for this command very carefully for details on the used options.

Execute in command prompt window also command `set` to see the list of predefined environment variables and their values like **APPDATA**.